# Remove almost duplicate values from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, duplicate-data

Need help!

i haven an array where the values are duplicated but not entirely,

somestring = 'abcd-abcd-123',
someOTHERstring223 = 'abcsd--adsf_12ds'

```
Array
        (
            [0] => somestring
            [1] => somestring-(don't know the delimiter)core
            [2] => somestring_(don't know the delimiter)-(don't know the delimiter)somethingelse
            [3] => someOTHERstring223
            [4] => someOTHERstring223_junkstring
            [5] => someOTHERstring223OTHERSTRING-somethingNEW

)
```

and the result i want it would be

```
somestring
someOTHERstring223
```

i just want the shortest values, cause somestring, somestring-(don't know the delimiter)core, somestring_(don't know the delimiter)-(don't know the delimiter)somethingelse are the same 
because they all start with somestring.

sorry everybody, i didn't asked the correct question.

i came up with the answer but i don't know if it the most efficient,

```
$coLL = array('somestring',"somestring-(don't know the delimiter)core","somestring_(don't know the delimiter)-(don't know the delimiter)somethingelse"
        ,"someOTHERstring223",'someOTHERstring223_junkstring','someOTHERstring223OTHERSTRING-somethingNEW');
    $coLL2 = $coLL;
    foreach($coLL as $coLLK=>$coLLV){  
        $flength = strlen($coLLV);
        foreach($coLL2 as $coLL2K=>$coLL2V){            
            if(strcmp($coLLV, $coLL2V) < 0){
                if(strlen($coLL2V)-$flength > 3){                    
                    unset($coLL2[$coLL2K]);
                }
            }        
        }        
    }
```

i set this limiter if(strlen($coLL2V)-$flength > 3)
because what if somestring1 comes up or somestring12 or somestring123 they are unique and they not match somestring.

Thanks everybody for your answers.

Comment: you can do it with `foreach`, `substr`, `strpos` (or `explode`). Have you tried something?

Comment: how do you know what the delimiter is? `somestring` and `someOTHERstring223` can both be reduced to `some` (the common prefix)

Comment: You asked the correct question, but the example could be a bit better so people don't fall into the trap ;)

Comment: You need to know the delimiters because otherwise, how to build the compare values? You can't expect code to magically do any ill misconception of some brain that just can't logically be expressed.

Comment: Ok, now delimiter is letter "S". Why not? Good delimiter. You should to know your delimiters.

Comment: Ok, now at *this* point I agree that OP has a bad question. note: maaan, pick better examples, `-` and `_` look almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<?php

    $array = array('apple','apple-core','apple-core-something','orange','orange-core','orange-core-someting');
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $entry) {
        $entry = explode('-',$entry);
        if (!in_array($entry[0],$result)) {
            $result[] = $entry[0];
        }
    }

    print_r($result);

?>
```

## [Working Example](http://codepad.org/r7Gx99DG)

Comment: Wroooong. example: `array("think-about-it", "a-bit")`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers all assume that `-` or some other token can delimit your shortest string. To do what you want without any delimiters, you could use something like [this code](http://codepad.org/icPid22i):

```
$yourArray = Array(
    0 => "apple",
    1 => "apple-core",
    2 => "apple-core-something",
    3 => "orange",
    4 => "orange-dot",
    5 => "orange-dot-something",
) ;
$resultArray = Array() ;

foreach($yourArray as $test) {
    if(strlen($test)==0) continue(1) ;        // Drop 0 length items.
    foreach($resultArray as $rkey => $rval) {
        if(strpos($test, $rval)===0) {        // If $test starts with $rval
            continue(2) ;                     // Continue outer foreach
        } elseif(strpos($rval, $test)===0) {  // If $rval starts with $test
            unset($resultArray[$rkey]) ;      // No longer shortest unique
            continue(1) ;                     // Continue inner foreach (and add $test)
        }
    }
    $resultArray[] = $test ;
}

var_dump($resultArray) ;
// array(2) {
//   [0]=>
//   string(5) "apple"
//   [1]=>
//   string(6) "orange"
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $store = array();

    foreach($data as $fruit) $store[] = array_shift(explode('-',$fruit));



print_r($store);
```

here $data is the array you have posted above

Comment: mmm that's just wrooong `array("think-about-it", "a-bit")`

Comment: @yi_H: i don't see a problem. the resulting array will be `array('think','a')` and that matches the OP's question (given that `-` is the hierarchy separator here)

Comment: I see the resulting array and think "well, that's a problem". the OP wanted to remove almost duplicates, now he's getting elements which weren't originally in the array.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem divide it:

1. Normalize each value to only contain the value you want to look for extact duplicates ([`strtok`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)).
2. Remove duplicates from the array ([`array_unique`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)).

[Demo](http://codepad.org/UFMVUUli):

```
function normalize($v)
{
   return strtok($v, '-_');
}

$normalized = array_map('normalize', $data);

$unique = array_unique($normalized);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "somestring"
  [3]=>
  string(18) "someOTHERstring223"
  [5]=>
  string(29) "someOTHERstring223OTHERSTRING"
}
```

You actually build a hash for each entry in the list. The hash is representing the comparison value of the original value. Then unique the hashes (and you actually want only the hashes).

What you need is a hash function that fulfills your needs. In the example above, the hash function is `normalize`.

If the outcome does not suit your needs, you need to adopt the hash function. I had chosen `strtok` as it seemed suitable for your (original) case. However if looking for a delimiter get's more complicated, you might look for regular expressions to specifiy a delimiter, like [`preg_split`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) or [`preg_replace`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

However to make use of a regular expression, you must know what your delimiter is, because bascially you follow the strategy to pad a string to build the hash. Without a well specified delimiter there is only try an error.

Comment: Wrooong. http://codepad.org/9JGlL1TY

Comment: @yi_H: I think you're misunderstanding something here, you provided input data that can not work with the that normalize function. If you change the input data, you need to change the normalize implementation as well. So you're just showing that divide and conquer actually works here.

Comment: I provided a perfectly valid input, so *your* code is wrong.

Comment: @yi_H what is wrong here is your comments.

Comment: sorry for pointing out why the provided codes aren't correct! And my comments seem to be right as the OP updated the question.

Comment: @yi_H: Never read code without it's context.

Comment: I read the context but how would your solution work if you don't know what the delimiter is? You are unable to tokenize.

Comment: @yi_H: Any you are unable to detect a pattern although, no matter how hard one tries. It's not completely solveable, one can only give different strategies how to solve it.

Comment: yes, if delimiters are interchangable then the OP has a bad question. but note that you removed in your example the delimiters in the output (huh) and chop at delimiter no matter whether there is duplicate or not. that's still bad. http://codepad.org/ZPqSc9aZ you have very good reputation points I am very shocked to see that you think this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
    foreach($a as $k2=>$v2) {
        if ($k2 == $k)
            break;
        if ($v == substr($v2, 0, strlen($v))) {
            unset($a[$k2]);
            break;
        }
        if ($v2 == substr($v, 0, strlen($v2))) {
            unset($a[$k]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: my solution just drops the elements for which there is an element in the array which is an exact prefix of the element. your updated question doesn't have a solution since you *have to know* what the delimiters are.

Comment: this takes the longest common prefix? (currently "some")

Comment: And yours makes assumptions for patterns: http://codepad.org/PN8PeVFa